# Type '_' has no member 'id' SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, struct, swiftui

So over the last couple hours, I've been trying to create a horizontal card stack that will show the most recent headlines for a project I am working on. Where I am at now, is holding up my entire flow, because my list cannot find my id variable in my results struct. Below I've attached the code, and any help would be appreciated.

[HeadlinesUI.swift - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7aid.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var header_image: String
    var summary: String
}

struct HeadlineUI: View {
    @State var results = [Result]()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                List(results, id: \.id) { items in

                }
                .onAppear(perform: loadData)
            }
        }
    }

    func loadData() {

    }
}

struct HeadlineUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HeadlineUI()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of your code - paste it in the body of the question instead. Thanks

Comment: You get both, that way you can see the error in relation.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `Result` as the name of a type. Not only is it too general to be descriptive (literally anything could be called a result: a number, a string, a table), but it also conflicts with the `Result` type build into the Swift standard library. I think that's causing the issue here.

Comment: Following your thought, I changed out Result with Article and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @thealexvond WHat happens if you explicitly specify `\Article.id`?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Cannot convert value of type 'WritableKeyPath<Article, Int>' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<_, _>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `Result` is a type in `Swift`, so you have to use a different name.

I went for:

```
struct MyResult: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var header_image: String
    var summary: String
}
```

since it has got an `id` you can make it `Identifiable`:

```
extension MyResult: Identifiable {}
```

as for the body:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(results) { result in
                Text(result.title)
            }
            .onAppear(perform: { self.loadData() })
        }
    }
}
```

You rather need a `ForEach` then a `List` and the builder cannot be empty. Also `onAppear` takes a closure as its argument. Once you make all the changes the `View` will behave as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much, I could not figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: @thealexvond In your defence, the compiler error was quite poor here. A big part of the problem was that with an empty list body, the return type of the closure you passed to `List` is unspecified, which leads to all guides of type errors that are hard for the compiler to explain.